# Viewing image fullscreen once button pressed

Tags: swift, image, uiview

I am working on an app which lets users attach up to 3 images to dropped map pins. Currently I have a small preview to view attached images, which are displayed on a UIView. I am trying to allow the user to view the full screen image once they press a preview button. Below is an example of the image preview buttons:

[image]

Here is the relevant code:

```
    // Image preview
    img1 = UIButton(frame:TCRectMake(x: 18,y:82,width:80,height:110))
    img1.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    img1.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
    img1.clipsToBounds = true
    img1.addTarget(self, action:"selectImage:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    popupView.addSubview(img1)

    img2 = UIButton(frame:TCRectMake(x: 100.8,y:82,width:80,height:110))
    img2.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    img2.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
    img2.clipsToBounds = true
    img2.addTarget(self, action:"selectImage:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    popupView.addSubview(img2)

    img3 = UIButton(frame:TCRectMake(x: 183,y:82,width:80,height:110))
    img3.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    img3.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
    img3.clipsToBounds = true
    img3.addTarget(self, action:"selectImage:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    popupView.addSubview(img3)

    ...

// Save image to document
func saveImageIntoDocument(resizeImage:UIImage,saveCompleted:((String)->())? = nil)
{
    let documentsUrl =  NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first!

    let timeStamp = "\((Int(Timestamp))).png"
    let filePath = documentsUrl.relativePath!.stringByAppendingString("/\(timeStamp)")
    if saveCompleted != nil
    {
        saveCompleted!(timeStamp)
    }
    UIImagePNGRepresentation(fixRotation(resizeImage))!.writeToFile(filePath, atomically: true)

}
```

This is the code for each preview button:

```
func image1Click(sender:UIButton)
{
    print(sender.tag)
}
func image2Click(sender:UIButton)
{
    print(sender.tag)
}
func image3Click(sender:UIButton)
{
    print(sender.tag)
}
```

I am new to swift so let me know if I missed anything :) If anyone could help me to view the previews full screen that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

This should help you out. This code uses the gestures, if you click on the image itself, then it goes to full screen but you can take at least some hints from it.

It works by creating a new image which covers everything. It has `TapGestureRecognizer` that hides the fullscreen image from its superView.

```
@IBAction func imgTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let imageView = sender.view as! UIImageView
    let newImageView = UIImageView(image: imageView.image)
    newImageView.frame = self.view.frame
    newImageView.backgroundColor = .blackColor()
    newImageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
    newImageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissFullscreenImage:")
    newImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    self.view.addSubview(newImageView)
}

func dismissFullscreenImage(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    sender.view?.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, nothing seems to happen when I implement this :( Maybe I am doing something wrong? Where should it go?

Comment: It should go to the ViewController where is the image.

Comment: Yes I placed it there but still no response when clicking the previews :( Do you know why? Thanks for your reply

Comment: Are there any errors? Or just no response? Did you add tap gesture also into your project from storyboard?

Comment: You are doing something wrong. I can't help you more if I do not see the whole project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116738/discussion-between-oscar-and-tarvo-maesepp).